# Django 1.8 is not able to load templates

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python Django web development. I am using Django 1.8.6 . I have just started to build one project. In the settings file, I have something like following:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

I have included templates folder in the 'DIRS' section. But Django is not able to load any template from that folder. It gives the following error message:

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

```
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
    /home/user/Python_Django/Web_App/DjangoVE/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html (File does not exist)

    /home/user/Python_Django/Web_App/DjangoVE/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/base.html (File does not exist)
```

For testing purpose, if I provide the absolute path for template folder in the 'DIRS' field, it still doesn't work out. Example:

```
'DIRS': ['/home/user/Python_Django/Web_App/myApp/templates']
```

Please point me my mistakes.

Comment: What is the location of the template you are trying to load, and how are you trying to load it?

Comment: Make sure you have pointed BASE_DIR to the right path.
Which url is being hit? Flow starts from url-->views-->templates. Templates get loaded based on the view and view is selected based on the url.

Comment: @Alasdair - I have added most of the settings.py file lines. Please look at the question again.

Comment: The `SECRET_KEY` should be kept secret. Change it before you deploy your site! The problem is that your app is not included in `INSTALLED_APPS`, see the answers below for more info.

Comment: As an aside, you can remove the `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting - it is deprecated in Django 1.8 by the new `TEMPLATES` setting.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `myapp` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then the app directories loader should pick up templates in `myapp/templates`.

Don't include `myapp/templates` in `DIRS`, it will be picked up by the app directories loader, because you have set `APP_DIRS` to `True`

The `DIRS` setting allows you to include project-wide directories. In your case, setting

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

will allow you to load templates from `/home/user/Python_Django/Web_App/templates`.

Comment: Yes, the OP's problem is that they have not included "myapp" in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: @Alasdair, I have included myapp in the INSTALLED_APPS, commented the line for 'DIRS', restarted the server, but still it shows - "TemplateDoesNotExist at /"

Comment: Please update your question with the new traceback. Is `myapp` included in the traceback now? Where is the `base.html` template you are trying to load?

Comment: Putting myapp in the INSTALLED_APPS didn't work, although putting 'DIRS': [(BASE_DIR + '/templates/'), ], in TEMPLATES worked for me.

Comment: Both approaches do different things. The one you need depends on the location of the template you are trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

to

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
)
```

This will make the templateloader find your files.

Comment: it is not working. Django still shows - "TemplateDoesNotExist at /"

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

to

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
)
```

This will make the templateloader find your files.

His answer is correct you can create a dir "templates" on your app !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlCwt.png)

;) thanks @Sebastian Wozny